# Как узнать самый верхний индекс элемента массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
$users = [
    [
        'email' => 'ignat.v@gmail.com',
        'name' => 'Игнат',
        'password' => '$2y$10$OqvsKHQwr0Wk6FMZDoHo1uHoXd4UdxJG/5UDtUiie00XaxMHrW8ka'
    ],
    [
        'email' => 'kitty_93@li.ru',
        'name' => 'Леночка',
        'password' => '$2y$10$bWtSjUhwgggtxrnJ7rxmIe63ABubHQs0AS0hgnOo41IEdMHkYoSVa'
    ],
    [
        'email' => 'warrior07@mail.ru',
        'name' => 'Руслан',
        'password' => '$2y$10$2OxpEH7narYpkOT1H5cApezuzh10tZEEQ2axgFOaKW.55LxIJBgWW'
    ]
];
```

Как например узнать какой индекс у элемента со значением email: "kitty_93@li.ru"

Comment: Перебирать массив в виде "ключ->значение", при нахождении нужного значения вернуть ключ.

Answer (score 1):

Перебираете элементы массива через `foreach`. Если у очередного элемента e-mail совпадает с искомым - записываете/выводите и обрываете цикл

Что-то типа такого:

```
foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
    if ($user['email'] === 'kitty_93@li.ru') {
        echo $key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно в одну строку

```
$key = array_search('kitty_93@li.ru', array_column($users, 'email'));
echo $key;
```

Одним циклом быстрее. Но это будет заметно на очень существенном объёме данных.

Comment: Стоит упомянуть  о том, что `array_column` вернёт 0-indexed массив. И если в исходном массиве ключи начинаются не с 0 - то в `$key` будет лежать не то что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

можно воспользоваться array_filter

```
$res = array_filter($users, function($x) { return $x['email']=='kitty_93@li.ru';} );
if($res) {
    echo(key($res));
}
else {
    echo 'Key not found';
}
```